# how to initialize AVCaptureMetadataOutput object?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

i am trying to us Apple's new feature [AVMetadataFaceObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataFaceObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in my ios 6 App that lets you recognize faces. basically what they want to make it happen is the create`AVCaptureMetadataOutput` object and Set it to an existing `AVAVCaptureSession` as an output.
so, i got squarecam Apple's sample code from this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

i have tryied to create the object like this:

```
    CaptureObject = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc]init];
objectQueue =       dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", NULL);//dispatch_queue_create("newQueue", NULL);
[CaptureObject setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:objectQueue];
```

and i am adding the input to the session here :

```
- (void)setupAVCapture
```

{
    NSError *error = nil;

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
else
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

// Select a video device, make an input
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
require( error == nil, bail );

isUsingFrontFacingCamera = NO;
if ( [session canAddInput:deviceInput] )
    [session addInput:deviceInput];

// Make a still image output
stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];
[stillImageOutput addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"capturingStillImage" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVCaptureStillImageIsCapturingStillImageContext];
if ( [session canAddOutput:stillImageOutput] )
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput ];
    **[session addOutput:CaptureObject];//////HERE///////**

     // Make a video data output
videoDataOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];

// we want BGRA, both CoreGraphics and OpenGL work well with 'BGRA'
NSDictionary *rgbOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:rgbOutputSettings];
[videoDataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES]; // discard if the data output queue is blocked (as we process the still image)

// create a serial dispatch queue used for the sample buffer delegate as well as when a still image is captured
// a serial dispatch queue must be used to guarantee that video frames will be delivered in order
// see the header doc for setSampleBufferDelegate:queue: for more information
videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
[videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoDataOutputQueue];

if ( [session canAddOutput:videoDataOutput] )
    [session addOutput:videoDataOutput];
[[videoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setEnabled:NO];

effectiveScale = 1.0;
previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
CALayer *rootLayer = [previewView layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
[rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];
[session startRunning];
```

}}

so basically the delegate should invoke this method :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
```

}

but non is happen.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended that you use the main queue for the metadata. That's the only thing I can see that might be wrong.

```
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *metadataOutput;
metadataOutput = [AVCaptureMetadataOutput new];
[metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[session addOutput:metadataOutput];
```